# Stock output of a script in a bash variable (QNAP QTS 4.0)

Tags: bash, qnap

I'm trying to stock the output of a script in a variable.
Here is the code of my script (delete.sh) :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Suppression de $1" >> /share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/delete.log
log=$(/share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/remoteSync -rm "$1")
echo $log >> /share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/delete.log̀
```

When I exec this script I got that in output :

```
[/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/remotesync] # soft/delete.sh "archivesPAO/3MONTAGE BORNE OZ 275x155.psd"
drivers : ("QMYSQL3", "QMYSQL", "QSQLITE")
Table hubicobject & hubicobjectLocal sucessfully reseted
Load container Object
" ATTENTION recuperation du prefix : archivesPAO/3MONTAGE BORNE OZ 275x155.psd"
Credentials
Refresh Token
"Upload  : 100% 0.00 octets/s fin dans : 00:00:00"
"Download  : 100% 0.00 octets/s fin dans : 00:00:00"
"Download  : 100% 0.00 octets/s fin dans : 00:00:00"
"https://lb9911.hubic.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_f5cb82ec59a615a1c56053608e0c6123"
"Download  : 100% 0.00 octets/s fin dans : 00:00:00"
"Download  : 100% 0.00 octets/s fin dans : 00:00:00"
"Temps pour inserrer 10000 entree : 0 ms"
[/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/remotesync] # cat soft/delete.log 

Suppression de archivesPAO/3MONTAGE BORNE OZ 275x155.psd
```

So I don't understand why I cannot stock this output in my shell variable.
Maybe it's because I work on a QNAP QTS 4.0 ? But I don't think so.

Comment: Is `remoteSync` perhaps printing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`?  `$(...)` will only grab `stdout`.  Also, in the source you provided you're `echo` is going to `delete.log` with an accent over the `g`, so perhaps you are just printing to the wrong file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `remoteSync` is writing also to standard error.

Give a try to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Suppression de %s\n" "${1}" >> /share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/delete.log
log="$(/share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/remoteSync -rm "${1}" 2>&1)"
printf "%s\n" "${log}" >> /share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/delete.log
```

If the `log` variable is only used to append the output to the log file, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Suppression de %s\n" "${1}" >> /share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/delete.log
/share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/remoteSync -rm "${1}" >> /share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/delete.log 2>&1
```

Both standard output and standard error are appended to the `delete.log` file, thanks to `>> ... 2>&1`.

`>> ...` appends standard output of the command to the file.

`2>&1` instructs the shell to redirect standard error (file descriptor 2) to the standard output (file descriptor 1). The standard error is appended as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the first option 
    #!/bin/bash
    printf "Suppression de %s\n" "${1}" >> /share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/delete.log
   log="$(/share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/remoteSync -rm "${1}" 2>&1)"
    printf "%s\n" "${log}" >> /share/MD0_DATA/remotesync/delete.log

And it's work as well. So remoteSync was also writing to standard error.

Thanks for your quick answers.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback, you should consider to accept my answer formaly then.